# session variables: setting a limit, and how it impacts performance?

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I would like some information, or good reference material on session variable limits i.e.

- How the **number** of declared session variables, impacts
  **memory** and **performance**,
- and if perhaps there is a reasonable 
  limit one should consider setting: in particular to a classic asp application IIS 6

NB: I should point out the session variables would only store Strings.

Perhaps in order not to make this too general, consider my question in regards to having a 64 bit server with about 8GB memory running IIS 6.0 - classic asp Web app. that would cater for a possible maximum of 20 concurrent users logged on.

The only answer I've had through my initial search is that there isn't a best practice, and that one should consider stresss testing tools: Web-performance-and-scalability-test-tool

Cheers.

Comment: A best practice is to avoid Session variables as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how the session variables are being handled, i.e if the session variables are eventually being pushed down to the browser as a base64 encoded cookie or set of cookies, then each cookie does have a maximum limit (4kb is the standard, I believe) and there are limits to a maximum number of cookies from a single domain (each browser has its own specification)

However, if you are using the server to manage all state, then the size of the session cookies is really dependent on the memory you have allotted to the web process. Additionally, its not simply about how much can the server handle, but at what point will the server show a degradation in performance given that disk paging will be used as an alternative, when the alloted memory to the process is full.

So, your own suggestion of stress testing the web app is a good one, but given that expect to only see 20 concurrent users and with 8GB on the machine, I wouldn't be worried about this problem.